# How to iterate through pandas row for statsmodel logit

Tags: python, pandas

I have a main dataframe
and a snapshot with the info I need from it.

| group | features |
| --- | --- |
| gr1. | f1,f2,f3 |
| gr2. | f2,f1,f4 |
| gr3. | f5,f4,f2 |

I'am trying to run my sm.Logit(y,X).fit(disp=0) is such way, so it would run by each line of the table above
so that it loc main df for first row like this: df.loc[df['group']=='gr1.']
and then run Logit with the X being all the features that are in column "features"

the outcome that I want is to have 3 Logit models, first one will have main df locked in a way it would only have values from group that are "gr1." `df.loc[df['group']=='gr1.']`
and then run Logit models based on the features of "gr1." which are "f1,f2,f3"

Answer (score 0):

Use `.iterrows()` method of pandas dataframe to iterate over the df.

```
for index, rowdf in df.iterrows():
    #Write logic.
    print(rowdf["group"])
```

Hope it helps.